# I can not catch response.data in axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

In my Vuetify app, i send a GET and the server response like this:
[image]

then in axios i try to catch that values with response.data.Autorizado and no catching. But if i only use response.data, the dta is showing, but obviouslly the server returns a lot of data, and i want to distribute the data.

This is my axios method:

```
      CargarCuenta(){
  this.$Progress.start();
    axios.get("Cuenta/Cuenta?rfc="+this.selectCuentas, {
      headers:{
        Authorization : "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem("token")
      }
    }).then(response =>{
      this.$Progress.finish();
      console.log(response.data);
      this.autorizado = response.data.Autorizado;
    }).catch(error => {
      this.$Progress.finish();
      console.log(error.response);
      this.snackbar = true;
      this.textSnackbar = error.response.data.Message;
    })
  }
```

The `this.autorizado` is place in the data() return, and in the template i use it  like this: `{{autorizado}}`.

Answer (score 0):

That console log `[{...}]` means you have an array with an object. So probably: `[{Autorizado:true}]`. There is no `response.data.Autorizado`, but there should be a `response.data[0].Autorizado`.